# Can I stop a docker container by its exposed port?

Tags: docker, workflow

I've around two to six projects with docker on my computer, which I use in parallel some times and have to manually stop some containers (mariadb, mongodb, php, nginx, apache) manually every time I want to use another project. Is there a way to stop those containers by its port, so I could simply do `docker stop -p 3306` and add it to my Makefile `stop` section? And if not, what way should I go to optimize this workflow.

I'm working on a mac with macOS 10.14.x and Docker desktop v18.09.2.

Comment: Have you looked into `docker-compose`? That lets you start and stop networks of containers together.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I'm aware of `docker-compose` and already use it but I can not `docker-compose stop mariadb` from another working directory. Image I am in Project A in folder A, but still have project B's services running. Now I want to stop them from project A. I only want to stop it, not remove it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming you can run `bash` one way to do it is to write a small script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

for id in $(docker ps -q)
do
    if [[ $(docker port "${id}") == *"${1}"* ]]; then
        echo "stopping container ${id}"
        docker stop "${id}"
    fi
done
```

`docker ps -q` will list the ids of the running containers. If the port mappings contain the passed in argument, it stops the container.
Put the script in the `PATH` and you can execute it anywhere:

```
stopByPort.sh 3306
```

Comment: Amazing! I wonder why Docker does not natively implement this... I'll post my own answer with my modified `.zprofile`-alias but accept yours. Thanks!

Comment: I think that as with any API design it's about balancing complexity and simplicity. Stopping a container by port mapping is probably not what many people need.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone looking for a way to use this in the terminal as an alias without calling the script or modifiend the PATH, here is @b0gusb script in my `.zprofile`:

```sh
docker-stop() {
  local port=${1:-none} # set a default otherwise it will stop all
  for id in $(docker ps -q); do
    if [[ $(docker port "${id}") == *"${port}"* ]]; then
      echo "Stopping container ${id}"
      docker stop "${id}"
    fi
  done
}
alias stop=docker-stop
```

Update:

I made a script from the above to use it like this in my `.zprofile`:

```sh
alias stop="bash ~/.zsh/docker-stop-by-port.sh"
```

**docker-stop-by-port**:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

port=$1

RED='\033[0;91m'
GREEN='\033[0;32m'
YELLOW='\033[0;33m'
RESET='\033[0m'

echo "" # empty first line

if [ -z $port ]; then
  echo -e "  ${YELLOW}Please specify a port to a running docker container!${RESET}"
  exit 0
fi

port_is_number_regex='^[0-9]+$'
if ! [[ $port =~ $port_is_number_regex ]]; then
  echo -e "  ${RED}Port can only be of type number${RESET}" >&2
  exit 1
fi

num_results=0
no_results=0
SECONDS=0

for id in $(docker ps -q); do
  ((num_results += 1))
  if [[ $(docker port "${id}") == *"${port}"* ]]; then
    echo -e "  Stopping container ${GREEN}${id}${RESET}"
    fin_id=$(docker stop "${id}")

    if [ $fin_id == $id ]; then
      echo -e "  ${GREEN}Done${RESET} in ${SECONDS}s"
    fi
  else
    ((no_results += 1))
  fi
done

if [ $num_results -eq $no_results ]; then
  echo -e "  No running container found with port ${YELLOW}${port}${RESET}"
fi
```

Comment: Really nice. I like it.