# Jenkins CI/CD how to stop running container and start the new pushed one

Tags: docker, jenkins, deployment, continuous-integration, devops

I am building a simple Jenkins pipeline, but when I push the deployment from git is said that the port is already used and I need to stop the running one.

I can't get the container ID

```js
stage("Deploy ") {
            steps{
                script {
                    
                    def dockerCmd = 'sudo docker run -p 8080:8080 -d --init biloocabba/kncare-app:1.0'
                    sshagent(['ec2-server-key']) {
                        sh "ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no ec2-user@18.184.112.174  ${dockerCmd}"
                    
                    }
                }
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can run script with something like this in `Jenkinsfile` (here I save the script with name stopByPort.sh)

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

for id in $(docker ps -q)
do
    if [[ $(docker port "${id}") == *"${1}"* ]]; then
        echo "stopping container ${id}"
        docker stop "${id}"
    fi
done
```

Execute:
`stopByPort.sh 8080`

Link references:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/56953427/14312225

Answer (score 0):

When your Jenkinsfile runs, you probably still have a running container with that name, blocking the same resources that you want to use.

So before you `docker run` the next container, you need to stop the existing one and remove it:

```
docker stop <containername>; docker rm <containername>
```

To be able to do that, you need to have a fixed name for your container rather than some randomly generated one. The name needs to be set like

```
docker run --name mycontainer ...
```

so later you can use

```
docker stop mycontainer; docker rm mycontainer
```

In your pipeline the combination will look the other way round:

```
docker stop mycontainer; docker rm mycontainer
docker run --name mycontainer ...
```

But be aware when running the new container you need to issue the exact command you used when running the old container. Plus you run into issues if `mycontainer` is not running at the time of the build. To prevent that there is another way.

Once your pipeline pushes the updated container to the registry, invoke a single run of [Watchtower](https://containrrr.dev/watchtower/) and that one will automatically update the container if a newer image is available.